# How to check if we have digits in column

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this script:

```
df1 = spark.sql("select * from table where field LIKE '%[0-9]%'")
display(df1)
```

This gives me empty DF.
I have table contains:
[image]

Comment: What is the exact data-type of the `field` column? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: do you want to match if string contain a single digit?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return rows where the field has at least one digit, then you should use regular expressions.  That is `RLIKE` and regular expression syntax:

```
select *
from table
where field rlike '[0-9]'
```

None of your fields contain the subquery `'[0-9]'` so none match `like`, which does not support `[]`.